React in Docker Network Error when using axios with localhost
I'm trying to run all my projects as containers on Docker. My react app tries calling the server using axios in chrome it fails:
export const fetchTreeSection = async (
  sectionId: number,
): Promise<TreeSection> => {
  const response = await axios.get<TreeSection>(
    `${API_BASE_URL}/api/ImageNet/treeSection/${sectionId}`,
  );
  return response.data;
};

Chrome inspector error:
http://localhost:5105/api/ImageNet/treeSection/0
message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK'
But if I paste http://localhost:5105/api/ImageNet/treeSection/0 into another tab it does return data correctly.
I do not want to use my machine IP address instead of localhost because I want to send this assignment off to be executed on other machines.
Here is the docker file that I run locally:
version: '3.8'
services:
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    container_name: mssql
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "StrongPassword123"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - mssql-data:/var/opt/mssql
    healthcheck:
      test: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P "StrongPassword123" -Q "SELECT 1" || exit 1
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 10s
      timeout: 3s

  importer:
    build:
      context: ./FinvizDataManager
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.importer
    depends_on:
      mssql:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: "Server=mssql,1433;Database=Finviz;Uid=sa;Pwd=StrongPassword123;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"

  server:
    build:
      context: ./FinvizDataManager
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.server
    depends_on:
      - importer
    environment:
      ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection: "Server=mssql,1433;Database=Finviz;Uid=sa;Pwd=StrongPassword123;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
    ports:
      - "5105:8080"

  react-app:
    build:
      context: ./finviz
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    environment:
      - VITE_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:5105
    depends_on:
      - server

volumes:
  mssql-data:
    driver: local

And the server config parts:
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowReactApp",
        policyBuilder => policyBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
});
...
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("AllowReactApp");
app.MapControllers();


@MindSwipe The React app is running in a browser outside the compose network, so using localhost is correct.

@HansKilian oops, you're right. I shouldn't comment before I've had my coffee.
